# CSS style ignored by <footer>

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Until now I used `<div>`s for header and footer, but as I'm moving to HTML5 I want to replace them with `<header>` and `<footer>` tags. The old version had the style definition

```
#footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

to remove the underlining from links. This works as expected. But after changing to the `<footer>` tag:

```
footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

the style is ignored. What am I doing wrong?

*(the full code, including styles, can be found [here](http://ryonen.net/index000.php))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specificity.

`#footer a` is an ID (`#footer`) and an element (`a`).

IDs are more specific than classes and classes are more specific than elements.

`footer a` isn't working because it's two elements, which is very low specificity, and it's being overwritten by `a:link` which is technically an element and a (psuedo)class, meaning it has higher specificity than two elements.

All you need to do is increase the specificity on the `footer a` declaration - either give the footer a class or an ID, or do `footer a:link, footer a:visited`.

Basically it boils down to IDs always override classes always override elements.  I believe it's 255 elements = 1 class and 255 classes = 1 ID (but you will never need to be that specific).  Inline styles and `!important` styles are more specific than anything, including IDs.  The basic way to calculate specificity is to count the number of IDs, classes, and elements (assuming you don't have to worry about inline styles or `!important`) in 0,0,0 notation (IDs,classes,elements).

`#footer a` is 1,0,1.

`a:link` is 0,1,1.

`footer a` is 0,0,2.

Those are organized from highest to lowest specificity.  To make `footer a` more specific than `a:link` you need to add at least 1 class or 1 ID to the declaration, e.g. something like `footer#footer a`, `footer.bottom a`, `footer a:link, footer a:visited`, and so forth (with the class or ID added to the HTML markup accordingly).  The last option would not require any HTML markup changed since you are simply overriding the `:link` and `:visited` psuedoclasses (which count as real classes in terms of specificity calculations, just as psuedo-elements like `:before` and `:after` count as elements).

The simplest of all solutions would be to change the `a:link, a:visited` style declarations to simply `a`, which means that declaration will be less specific than the one in the footer and you won't need to alter anything else for it to start working.

Specificity is arguably the single most important concept you need to master in CSS.  Here are some good resources to learn more:

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity (CSS Tricks)](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [CSS Specificity (Smashing Mag)](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [CSS Specificity (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [Understanding CSS Specificity (Nettuts)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 3):

Specificity is the issue there...

`a:link, a:visited` overrides `footer a` so make it

```
footer a:link, 
footer a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But why did it work in the old version then?

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn you had `#footer` which is nothing but an id selector, which is more specific compared to the pseudo selectos.. and hence it worked, assign an `id` to your `footer` element and use the selector you are already using but with a `#` before and it will work

Comment: Thanks, but I explained I'm exactly removing the `<div id="footer">` in favor of the `<footer>` tag.

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn I discussed CSS specificity in a bit more detail in my answer below as well.

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn yes and it failed because you got rid of the `id` on the element, `id` was more specific, so if you want, declare `id="footer"` on the `footer` element and use `#footer a {/*your styles*/}` and it will work

Comment: OK, I understand about the specificity precedence, but wouldn't adding an `id` to the `<footer>` tag defy its purpose? Then I could just have stayed with `<div>`s for everything, right?

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn check my answer! You can just replace the `a:link, a:visited` declaration with `a` and it will work right away.  Otherwise you need to add a class (or an ID) to the footer.

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn `footer` gives a semantic meaning to your html document, it has nothing to do with the selector, assign a class instead on the `footer` and use something like `footer.class_name a:visited, footer.class_name a:link {}` and your selector will just work fine, you should learn about specificity, also, again, using `footer`, `header`, `aside`, `section` has nothing to do with CSS, CSS just selects the elements and apply properties, the tags you use in the document provides meaning to the content they are holding

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn it's also important to note that HTML5 elements like `footer` are not recognized by some older browsers (Internet Explorer 8 and below) so if you want people on IE7 or IE8 to use your site you need to include a JS polyfill for these elements such as Modernizr or the simple HTML5shiv

Comment: @Ennui: I already read and upvoted your comprehensive answer. Thanks. I'll wait until tomorrow before accepting, in case there would be more answers.

Comment: Also @Mr.Alien is correct, the purpose of HTML5 semantic elements is exactly that - semantics.  `footer` versus a `div` with id `footer` is still different because that `footer` HTML5 element is interpreted by screen readers, search engine crawlers, etc differently than `<div id="footer">` might be.  You should try to think of markup and CSS as two functionally independent things.